# How to write python to fetch page information(user and password needed)

Tags: python

I want to fetch html information(`http://192.168.11.1/userRpm/AssignedIpAddrListRpm.html`) about Router through http request with Python. For example, The router IP is 192.168.11.1, In the http request, the user is admin, and the password is admin. How can I do this with Python.Can you give me an example? Thanks!

Comment: How would you authenticate in the browser?

Comment: Login that page firstly, and input user and password.

Comment: I haven't written Python, and it's a little complicated to send and analyse http packet. So I want to finish this by Python. Maybe this question is a little stupid.

Comment: Since we don't knwo how this page is doing authentication, we can not help you. You will have to understand first which authentication method is used.

Comment: It's like this: [Router Manage](http://www.tp-link.us/faq-73.html).

Comment: Take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication#Client_side What Python library do you use as the HTTP client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests)

```
$ pip install requests
```

Use it with basic auth (or whichever the webserver uses)

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth

requests.get('http://192.168.11.1/userRpm/AssignedIpAddrListRpm.html',
              auth=HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'password'))
```

For more info, [see here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/)

Comment: When I run `pip install requests`, the output is `'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback`

Comment: Something is wrong with your python environment then :(

Comment: I use `PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin/python2.7` in my linux, but it still outputs `import sitecustomize` failed;

Comment: You shouldn't need that at all. You could try just running `python -v -c "import sitecustomize"` as well

Comment: I run `python -v -c "import sitecustomize"`firstly, and then `pip install requests`. The output is always `'import sitecustomize' failed; use -v for traceback`.